# How to compare whole 2D array rows not elements

Tags: c

For a function of the form.

```c
bool contains_equal_rows(int height, int width, const int ar[height][width])
```

How do I find if a row is repeated? I can see how you can set a bool to `true` if a row is repeated, but how do you avoid returning `false` too early?

Problem description:

> Write a function that gets a 2-d array of given dimensions of ints.
>   It returns true if the array contains two rows with exactly the same values in the same order, and returns false otherwise.
>
> ```c
> bool contains_equal_rows( int height, int width, const int ar[height][width])
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> On input
>
> ```
> {{1,2,3,4},
> {2,3,4,1},
> {1,2,3,4}}
> ```
>
> it returns true.
>
> On input
>
> ```
> {{1,2,3,4},
> {2,3,4,5},
> {3,4,5,6}}
> ```
>
> it returns false.
>
> On input
>
> ```
> {{1,1,1,1},
> {2,2,2,2},
> {1,1,1,6}}
> ```
>
> it returns false.

My attempt so far:

```
bool contains_equal_rows(int height, int width, const int array[height][width])
{
  int w = width;
  int h = height;
  bool test = false;
  bool matchedRow = false;

  for(int m = 0; m < h; m++)
  {
    for(int n = 0; n < w; n++)
    {
        if( array[m][n] == array[m][n-1] )
        {
            test = true;
        }
        else
        {
            test = false;
        }
    }

    if(test == true)
    {
        matchedRow = true;
    }
  }
  return matchedRow;
}
```

The problem with my code is that I'm only comparing a row with the one before it, and can't figure out how to compare one row with all.

Expected results as shown in description.

Comment: Sorry, Im having trouble figuring out how to compare a row to ALL the rest of the rows. Currently my code only compares the current row to the row before it. thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you avoid returning true for "equal" if only the first element of the row is identical? What I want to illustrate is, that your problem is already earlier. In the third example, you will incorrectly return "true", because the first element of first and third row is equal. Think how to avoid that.

Comment: Loop over rows from first to second-to-last (`i`). Inside the loop, loop over rows from `i+1`'th to last (`j`). Inside that loop, loop over columns from first to last (`k`) and compare `i,k` to `j,k`, if there is a false, exit the innermost loop. If the innermost loop is not exited prematurely, return `true` globally.

Comment: thank you!  that helps alot. i think i see what you both mean.

Comment: @Yunnosch im trying to avoid that problem by then testing if test is still true after checking the whole row, and then setting matchedRow to true if that is true in the last if statement

Comment: I was wrong with my example of failing test case. Your code will only be wrong if the **last** lement of a row happens to be identical, not the first. "Luckily" (actually bad luck), there is no test case with two rows which are different but identical in the last element. Make up one your self and try it. E.g. `{{1,2,3,4},{7,6,5,4},{32,16,8,4}}`. (The mising test case I consider a shortcoming of the question, not of your code....)

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. And I really like your nick, which I assume is a quote from one of my favorite books.

Comment: thank you for the welcome! haha yes it is a reference to the book, and my physical likeness! the code will be tested with additional tests in  the automated grading system, which will certainly have most cases. didnt even see that thanks!

Comment: Because of a hidden characteristic of one of the answers, I'd like to know, whether the input can have more than three rows. I interpret the parameters to imply that more rows are possible.

Comment: yes it can be greater than 3 rows, and will likely be one of the things that it will be marked for. question is out of 30 points (of 100 for the whole problem set)

Comment: hey you deleted your comment about being sentimental! Sorry got busy! I'm all for being sentimental! Really appreciate the kindness!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the clearest way to do this is to break down the task, by creating a separate function to compare two rows; then run through the array, checking each row against all others:

```
bool rows_are_equal(int width, const int row1[], const int row2[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) if (row1[i] != row2[i]) return false;
    return true;
}

bool contains_equal_rows(int height, int width, const int *array[])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) { // Check each row ...
        for (int test = row + 1; test < height; ++test) { // ... against all the others:
            if (rows_are_equal(width, array[row], array[test])) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notice that I've changed the format of the last argument to your `contains_equal_rows` function, as the way you had it written is not standard C.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Are you aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ? What is your opinion on the discussion?

Comment: @Yunnosch Which is why I tend to add the last line/sentence in such answers! If this is, indeed homework (seems quite likely, I agree), then the OP is free to ask how/why the answer I provided works. But it's a vague area, full of grey lines, so let's not get too sanctimonious or judgmental.

Comment: thank you for the response! I wasnt looking for an answer but this does help alot and is much much clearer than what i had. I'm trying everything suggested hear out and will get back to everyone!

Comment: just as a note re: not using *array - the prof asked to leave it as is because of the automated grading is structured to use it as such. not sure why so left it as such.

Comment: @bigfriendlygiant Fine - if it works as `array[height][width]` on your compiler, then use it! It didn't compile on mine (Visual Studio), so I changed it.

Comment: @Yunnosch would you agree this is the most complete answer to my problem as a reference for anyone that comes across this? just to bring a close to the discussion? It doesn't have the limitations i feel like other approaches are likely to have a hard time overcoming.

Comment: My opinion on what is most helpful for others is irrelevant for you as the asker. Just accept the answer that has helped **you** most. Maybe consider whether getting a code solution  is really the best help for you as a learner. Later, when you have more reputation and can upvote consider each answer you encounter anywhere (not only on your own questions) for its helpfulness from point of view of others. (On the other hand, I really appreciate, that you obviously seem to really think about the idea of StackOverflow as a Q/A collection. So very much welcome again.)

Comment: @Adrian what would happen when row=height-1? test becomes equal to height then!

Comment: hmm i think the idea of splitting it into two functions is the most creative and will help a student think more outside of the box of just making more and more complex conditions. although @Turamarth helped me frame my own understanding.

Comment: @Abdulkareem Yes, but that's not a problem, because the inner `for` loop doesn't run.

Comment: @bigfriendlygiant - Although you can only "accept" one answer (and it's up to you which one you choose), **you now have sufficient rep** to "upvote!" I would recommend the latter for any/all answers that have helped you. What Yunnosch has said is good, general advice for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks to all of you! and thank you for raising that question Abdul made me think about it!

Comment: also - the issue of needing to start from 1 (ie the second row) for looping through the height doesnt apply to this solution if im understanding it correctly? @Yunnosch

Comment: It does. Here `for (int test = row + 1`.

Comment: I use a similar 'logic' but apply it in reverse! The idea of @user3733801 is to compare the current 'test' with all rows **before** it; in my case, I compare the current row with all rows **after** it! But it is important - whichever way you go - to avoid comparing a row with ***itself***.

Comment: mmm the limiting structure of the testing  provided with the assignment is giving me a hard time in understanding how to fix that. it only tests 2 arrays with 3 rows.

Answer (score 3):

You should start your outer loop from 1.
And in your inner loop compare `array[0]` against `array[m]`,
before entering into the inner most loop set test to false
as soon as test is true you can break out of both loops and return true.

Comment: Please explain the reason for your very good tip of starting from 1. Please explain why comparing 0 to m is needed (I think it is not enough, think of input with more than three rows, but for guranteed three rows it works, which might be very confusing). The rest of the answer is good and very appropriate for helping somebody with homework. May I recommend to take the [tour]?

Answer (score 2):

You could add another for-loop:

```
For each row `i`:  
    For every other row `j`:  
        For each column `k` compare `array[i][k]` and `array[j][k]`
```

Something like this for example:

```
int w = width;
int h = height;
boolean test = false;

for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < h; j++) {
        test = true;
        for(int k = 0; k < w; k++)
        {
            if( array[i][k] != array[j][k] )
            {
                test = false;
            }
        }
        if(test == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Are you aware of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ? What is your opinion on the discussion?

Comment: thank you for the response! I'm trying everything suggested hear out and will get back to everyone! I think im going to try to implement this first, instead of just copying pasting the above suggestion to fully understand how to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
bool contains_equal_rows(int height, int width, const int array[][])
{
int horizontalItr = 0;
int verticalItr = 0;
int verticalItrItrUtility = 0;

bool testIfRowIsRepeated = true;
bool foundAtLeastOneRowIsRepeated = false;
bool finalAnswerRowIsRepeated = false;

for (verticalItr; verticalItr < height - 1; verticalItr++)
{
    for (verticalItrItrUtility = verticalItr; verticalItrItrUtility < height - 1 ; verticalItrItrUtility++)
    {
        testIfRowIsRepeated = true

        for (horizontalItr; horizontalItr < width; horizontalItr++)
        {
            if (array[verticalItrItrUtility][horizontalItr] != array[verticalItrItrUtility + 1][horizontalItr])
            {
                testIfRowIsRepeated = false;
                horizontalItr = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (testIfRowIsRepeated == true)
        {
            foundAtLeastOneRowIsRepeated = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundAtLeastOneRowIsRepeated)
    {
        finalAnswerRowIsRepeated = true;
        break;
    }
}

return finalAnswerRowIsRepeated;
```

}

didn't tested it, but it seems fine to me,
couple of things, 
1. i changed your variables name, to more clear names.
2. the check is supposed to be against the next rows, not the preveious ones.
3. the concept is that i assume each row is the repeated one, until the loop proves me otherwise.
enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works only for your test cases specs i.e, with width=4. You can create an outer for loop for the current row to compare it's elements with every row, notice that when it compares with itself flag would be equal to width hence you should avoid comparing it with itself using "continue", if at anytime all 4 elements of our current row are same to any other row then flag becomes equal to width(i.e, 4) and we return true immediately, if we come out of the outer loop having counter "k" then none of the 2 rows are same and we return false

```
bool contains_equal_rows(int height, int width, const int array[][4])
{
int flag = 0;

for (int k = 0;k < height;k++)
    for (int m = 0; m < height; m++)
    {
        if (m == k)
            continue;
        for (int n = 0; n < width; n++)
            if (array[k][n] == array[m][n])
                flag++;
            else
                break;
        if (flag == width)
            return true;
        else
            flag = 0;
    }
return false;
}
```